# mediaelement.js - hide controls for first video only

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to put together an ad pre-roll similar to this example (back-to-back videos):

```
<video width="640" height="360" src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" 
controls="controls" preload="none"></video>

<script>
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(media, node, player) {
        media.addEventListener('ended', function() {

            media.setSrc('video2.mp4');
            media.load();
            media.play();

        }, false);
    }
});
</script>
```

I need to hide the player controls showing during the first video, then add the controls for the second. Here's what I have tried:

- various methods of hiding the control bar via jquery, but it always reappears on hover (over the controls div).
- unbinding that hover. No luck.
- starting out without the controls attribute in the video tag, then adding it for the second video, but you can always get the controls on hover.

The only other idea I had was to set the features array to just the progress bar for the first video, then add the rest of the control features for the second video, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the div I was positioning on top of the player during the ad (to prevent interaction) was not covering up the very bottom of the player, resulting in the hover action. Correctly overlaying the div resolved my issue.